# resizing snapped windows together with ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, gdm

I want to be able to snap two windows together, then when I click on the border of the two windows and drag left or right, resize them as a whole, that is, if I resize the window on the left 50% smaller, the window on the right will take up that space and increase in size as I drag.

Which settings need to be enabled for this to happen?  I am on Ubuntu 18.  I've seen many posts on it, but none are working for me.

Comment: Are you running compiz - since you tagged your post with compiz? Then you may be  are running the Unity or xfce desktop instead of the standard desktop? Please clarify which desktop you use and carefully correct your tags if needed. It is obvious that such feature is determined by the window manager you are currently using, which according to your tag would be compiz.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am running GDM3. Gnome DE with Gnome Shell WM.